# CSS: How can I fix the background image and also create a text box?

Tags: html, css, text, background-image

I’m studying Web Development for a few months and in the meantime re-creating my personal website. It also helps me to practice what I’ve learned so far. However I got some problems that I can’t solve on my own.

I’ve created a homepage and two index content pages so far. But I can’t manage to fix the background image. The proportion of the image changes on every page. Here’s the CSS code I wrote:

```
html {
background-image: url("file:///C:/Users/Rumeysa/Documents/VS Code Projects/rumeysagelgi.com/resources/jpegs/8.jpg");
background-color: #cccccc; 
background-size: cover; 
}
```

Besides that I styled the h4 element as a box to include text content. I want to set the text box to proper dimensions and make it scroll when the text is longer than the box can cover. Here is current code:

```
h4 {
font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
font-size: small;
font-weight: normal;
background-color: whitesmoke;
text-align: justify;
line-height: 120%;
border: 10px groove rgb(239, 230, 250);
border-radius: 2%;
padding: 5px;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

I upload a few screenshots for better understanding. I want background image to look like as at the homepage. I really would appreciate help from experienced developers. Thank you.

[image: homepage]
[image: index-page-1]
[image: index-page-2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background image's dimensions are changing because of the `background-size: cover;` property.

**`background-size: cover`**

> Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#cover)

Change it to `auto` to [keep the original proportions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#auto).

Now, for the text, wrap the heading tag in a `div` and add this css:

```css
div {
    white-space: nowrap; /*important - see reference*/
    width: /*add your width*/;
    height: /*add your height*/;
    overflow: auto;
}

h4 {
    overflow: inherit;
    /*no need to inherit white-space, it will be inherited automatically*/
}
```

> In order for overflow to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (height or max-height) or white-space set to nowrap.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Description)

Comment: Thank you. I edited the code and it looks so much better now. However the text box's top and bottom borders disappear while scrolling the box. Have you an idea how to prevent that?

Comment: @RumeysaGelgi Did you add the border to `h4` wrapper? If not, add the borders to the `<div>` wrapper. It will work.